# Updating an image from internet

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to do a simple aplication with a button and an image.
This button updates that image, that is a imagem from a security cam.
triyng this(and a lot of other things)

```
Image image1 = new Image();
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
src.UriSource = new Uri("http://cameras/upload/img/CAM_INTERNET_1.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
image1.Source = src;
```

The image from web is refreshed every 30 seconds.
Does anyone have an ideia?

Comment: Data is okay, whats your question here ? whats the actual problem ? Also, its not relative url, its absolute URL

Comment: You need to add the error message you're experiencing

Comment: on button click you need to reset the src to encourage it to redownload, otherwise its storing the old value image, perhaps? just making stuff up really, you asked for ideas and thats mine XD

Comment: Are you sure that your url is relative?

Comment: @nkchandra:yeah, it's absolute. i was trying a lot of things and forgot to change. My questions is why the image doesn't change, and what is wrong(because there is no change).

Comment: @RhysW: any recomendations to do that?

Comment: @Steve Mayne: there's no error. Simple doesn't update.

Comment: The URL in your code, is it valid ? when I paste it in the browser, it said not found !! Also, you should edit the question with what you are expecting and what is happening. Its very unclear !!!

Comment: @nkchandra the url is http://cameras.praiagrande.sp.gov.br/upload/img/CAM_INTERNET_1.jpg. Something changed when i was writing the post... And about the question, i think is pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the device sees the Uri as unchanged and resorts to giving you a cached version of the image. I'd try appending some bogus querystring to the Uri to make it unique to see if that gets past the caching.

```
var image1 = new Image();
var src = new BitmapImage();
var uri = string.Format(
    "http://cameras/upload/img/CAM_INTERNET_1.jpg?{0}", 
    DateTime.Now.Ticks); 
src.UriSource = new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative);
image1.Source = src;
```

Note that I've not tried this, so it may or may not work.

Comment: as you said, doesn't work. The image is not loading, but i still trying making a little changes in your code. Tks.